# How to configure Symfony1 PHP ORM to use PostgreSQL SERIAL (auto-increment) column

Tags: php, postgresql, orm, symfony1, entity-relationship

Here i'm facing new issue on create auto increment id.
I'm new to ORM Entity creation, here i struggle with create auto increment id using Entity relation its not working, every time insert record its stores empty value but i used query its working.

My Query :

```
 ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN autoincrement SERIAL;
```

But i tried to create auto increment id using entity its not working, please help me if you can.

My ORM entity file :

```
autoincrement:
      type: integer
      column: autoincrement
      generator:
        strategy: AUTO
```

My PHP File :

```
/**
     * @var integer
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue
    */
    protected $autoincrement;
```

Comment: Come on, you did not even try.  Google "How to create auto increment on postgresql"...

Comment: i tried lot of times, if i run query ALTER TABLE test ADD COLUMN autoincrement SERIAL; directly its working, but i set as entity its not working

Comment: @Nic I think this may be better understood as a PHP Symfony1 ORM problem. They added the column fine. The title is just misleading.